# How do I do this replace regex in python?

Tags: python, regex, string, text

Given a string of text, in Python:

```
s = "(((((hi abc )))))))"
s = "***(((((hi abc ***&&&&"
```

How do I replace all non-alphabetic symbols that occur more than 3 times...as blank string

For all the above, the result should be:

```
hi abc
```

Comment: What should the output be if the input is `"(&*hello!@#"`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work: `\W{3,}`: matching non-alphanumerics that occur *3 or more* times:

```
>>> s = "***(((((hi abc ***&&&&"
>>> re.sub("\W{3,}", "", s) 
'hi abc'
>>> s = "(((((hi abc )))))))"
>>> re.sub("\W{3,}", "", s) 
'hi abc'
```

Comment: @John : Correct.  The examples included '***', so I shot a guess that he wanted 3+...  I was confident that, given this solution, he could figure out how to add one.  (That's why I italicized _3 or more_)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to replace any sequence of non-space non-alphamerics (e.g. `'!?&'` as well as your examples), @Stephen's answer is fine.  But if you only want to replace sequences of three or more *identical* non-alphamerics, a *backreference* will help:

```
>>> r3 = re.compile(r'(([^\s\w])\2{2,})')
>>> r3.findall('&&&xxx!&?yyy*****')
[('&&&', '&'), ('*****', '*')]
```

So, for example:

```
>>> r3.sub('', '&&&xxx!&?yyy*****')
'xxx!&?yyy'
```

Comment: +1, I came back to add backreferences to my answer, but I'll let you have it... :)

Comment: @John, yep, but as @Stephen already explained, it's more believable that the OP did a slight mistake in English, than a total blooper in his example of desired behavior;-).

Answer (score 0):

You can't (easily, using regexes) replace that by a "blank string" that's the same length as the replaced text. You can replace it with an empty string `""` or a single space `" "` or any other constant string of your choice; I've used `"*"` in the example so that it is easier to see what is happening.

```
>>> re.sub(r"(\W)\1{3,}", "*", "12345<><>aaaaa%%%11111<<<<..>>>>")
'12345<><>aaaaa%%%11111*..*'
>>>
```

**Note carefully:** it doesn't change "<><>" ... I'm assuming that "non-alphabetic symbols that occur more than 3 times" means the same symbol has to occur more than 3 times". I'm also assuming that you did mean "more than 3" and not "3 or more".